# Stand alone HBASE server

Tags: hbase

I have installed hbase and set the property hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort to 2222

```
 <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
  </property>
```

When i try to create a table using a curl command

`curl -v -d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><table><name>users</name>        <columnfamilies><columnfamily><name>habbit</name></columnfamily></columnfamilies></table>"  -H "Content-Type:text/xml"   http://127.0.0.1:2222/api`

THE REPLY I GET

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 2222
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 2222

POST /api HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 Host: localhost:2222 Accept: */* Content-Type:text/xml Content-Length: 152


Empty reply from server

Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Closing connection #0
```

I know hbase server is running because i am able to hit

```
http://localhost:60010/master-status
```

The question is it should not give me an empty response and the table is also not created

Bapu

Answer (score 1):

I had missed a step of starting the hbase rest server

/bin/hbase rest start

with this things atarted working for me.

Also i was using a old ruby client to connect to hbase correct way to connect to hbase from ruby client is here

https://github.com/greglu/hbase-stargate#readme